# How can I import GTFS files into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

[GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) is a common format for public transportation schedules.

> The General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS) defines a common format
>   for public transportation schedules and associated geographic
>   information. GTFS "feeds" allow public transit agencies to publish
>   their transit data and developers to write applications that consume
>   that data in an interoperable way.

Now, I have a trace in GTFS format, including several `.txt` files (tables). **How can I import it into MySQL?**

Comment: afaik data from GTFS emits several csv filess , which can be further imported into mysql using LOAD DATA INFILE <your-file-name> FIELDS <field-list> SEPARATED BY ',' SKIP FIRST 1 ROW

Comment: @Satya How to assign a specific database? (I created several databases in my machine)

Comment: Use `LOAD DATA INFILE <file> INTO TABLE <table> FIELDS <field-list> TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES`, or something like that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Also, I think you're confusing "database" and "table"; technically, there are databases, which contain schemas, which contain tables made up of columns and other organization entities, which contain rows of data.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja store the trace in a database (say `gtfs`). `gtfs` contains several tables (each table corresponds to a text file).

Comment: Okay, so for each file, `LOAD DATA INFILE <file-for-table-x> INTO TABLE \`gtfs\`.<table-x> FIELDS <field-list> TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES`, replacing <file-for-table-x>, <table-x>, and <field-list> appropriately. Either that or call `use \`gtfs\`;` beforehand, and ignore the `\`gtfs\`.` part.

Comment: Oh, right, this is MySQL. "Schemas" (in other SQL dialects) are called "Databases" in MySQL... roughly. There's still a slight conceptual difference, in that databases contain schemas, but in MySQL you effectively operate on the Database level, whereas you operate on the Schema level in many other RDBMSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of **@Shotgun Ninja**, **@Satya**, I make it. Here is what I do.

```
cat load.sql | mysql -p -u root
```

`load.sql` is based on `github/sbma44/py-gtfs-mysql`, [here](https://github.com/sbma44/py-gtfs-mysql/blob/master/sql_better/load.sql). The main code is as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS gtfs;
USE gtfs

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS agency;
-- agency_id,agency_name,agency_url,agency_timezone,agency_phone,agency_lang
CREATE TABLE `agency` (
    agency_id INT(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    agency_name VARCHAR(255),
    agency_url VARCHAR(255),
    agency_timezone VARCHAR(50),
    agency_phone VARCHAR(255),
    agency_lang VARCHAR(50)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'agency.txt' INTO TABLE agency FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I share it on GitHub: [tisseo_toulouse_gtfs](https://github.com/SparkandShine/data_analysis/tree/master/traces/tisseo_toulouse_gtfs).